# usefulness of microsoft data access application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am planning to start learning asp.net mvc. And also I want to learn Microsoft's Data Access application block. But I dont want to waste time in MDAC block if theres a better option to go for, or if MVC provides any good feature than MDAC. As I have heard MVC architecture automatically generates code.
So, please guide me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand this question. Please ask a more clear question.

Comment: are you looking for a way to access data in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not part of MVC per se, but I'd recommend using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework) over the Data Access application block if you're interested in a pure MS object relational mapping.  You could also look at [nHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) or a variety of other ORMs to accomplish this.  Any of these would suffice as the basis for the M(odel) in an MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Nerddinner example application, there is also the data access included. The tutorials are extensive: http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/

Don't work with MDAC block if you are not forced to! Try NHibernate, Entity-Framework or LINQ instead.